# Accessing django project outside LAN systems

Tags: django, google-chrome

I want to configure Django project such that I can access the data from outside world(from any computer or mobile which is connected to internet).
  But not connected on LAN or same WiFi network.
    Can someone help with the steps.

Regards
Neha

Comment: It's called web hosting.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. Can you please suggest something for trail basis.

Comment: Of course. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_hosting_service

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to deploy your project to the Internet? In that case, you might want to consider a hosting provider like Heroku, Amazon Web Services, DigitalOcean or another Virtual Private Server (VPS) hosting provider.

Comment: Thanks Anthony.I am a bit new to this.Do I need to configure some webserver like Apache or Nginx and after I need to host it.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You're welcome :-). Whether you deploy with Apache or Nginx depends on the hosting provider you choose and the way you configure your servers. It might pay to research how you would deploy a Django site with a particular service provider, like Heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python